# AngularJS Validation doesn't check step-Restriction of a HTML number input

Tags: angularjs, html, forms

Why is AngularJS not checking the `step="0.01"` attribute of the second input? For `min` and `max` attributes it works perfectly, but not for the `step` attribute.

For example: The input 0,005 will evaluate `submitNewEntryForm.submitNewEntryAmount.$valid` to true, but it shouldn't.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div ng-app="">

  <form class="form-inline" name="submitNewEntryForm">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="submitNewEntryForm.submitNewEntrySubject.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error'">
      <label for="subject">Betreff:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" required name="submitNewEntrySubject" ng-model="submitNewEntrySubject">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="submitNewEntryForm.submitNewEntryAmount.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error'">
      <label for="amount">Betrag:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" required name="submitNewEntryAmount" ng-model="submitNewEntryAmount" step="0.01" min="0" max="99999">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!(submitNewEntryForm.submitNewEntrySubject.$valid && submitNewEntryForm.submitNewEntryAmount.$valid)" ng-click="">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add regex, like `\d+\.\d{0,2}`
You can use HTML5 `pattern="^\d+\.\d{0,2}$"` or `ng-pattern="^\d+\.\d{0,2}$"`. It changes error state without limiting html input to 2 decimal points.

To be strict, you should use `^\d{1,5}\.\d{,2}$`

If you want number to have 2 decimal point but allow it to be without leading `0` like `.01`, you can use `^\d*\.\d{2}$`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize that there was a Angular directive for the `step` attribute. If you look at the documentation, it seems to be a very recent addition.

I find no mention of the step attribute until you get to a build of the un-released 1.5.9 version.

Latest version: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

Notice in the "Usage" and "Arguments" sections that the `step` directive is listed. Now use the pull down menu in the upper left to change the version, and observe that there is no mention of the `step` directive.

Either this is a brand new, unreleased feature... or perhaps the documentation for older versions is not correct :)

Comment: `step` is HTML attribute of `input` tag so you can't find it in Angular documentation

Comment: @v-andrew the second sentence of my answer says that the `step` directive for number inputs is documented in the very latest build of Angular 1.5.9. And if you read the docs, they say it performs the validation that the OP was interested in :)

Comment: However your answer has nothing to do with question asked.